# How do I remove microsoft windows on an asus desktop

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu but Windows is still there. My old Ubuntu CD won't work on the ASUS Desktop as there's no CD drive. How do I completely remove Windows?

Comment: There is a guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows)

Answer (score 0):

If the cd/dvd drive doesn't work you can make a bootable USB drive with ubuntu.
See [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to know how.

Then boot from the USB and there format the windows partition and install a fresh copy of ubuntu on that partition.

[Here's](https://superuser.com/a/163323) a step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

or after installing a Live USB over at linuxpendrive, start ubuntu and open gparted from your unity launcher. You will see all of your Windows and Linux partitions. After deleting your Windows partitions you could just expand your linux drives e.g. /home to use the space without wiping out your current linux install.

Answer (score 0):

You got no dvd writer. so you can make bootable Pendrive using software like `unetbootin`. By using this pendrive you can boot ubuntu as live os without installing it then with the help of

> disks

program available in ubuntu you can make changes to your partition and changes them as per your needs.